# How can I fetch timestamp data in my timezone?

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, timezone, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra 3.11.13 and I have table with timestamp column. Where are my data stored in terms of +0 timezone, i.e. `2022-10-14 07:51:00.000000+0000`, but I am hosting in Kazakhstan GMT+6
I want to export certain rows and certain period of time. When I am exporting into CSV, I am getting a file with timezone +0.
I tried to query like `select * from table_name where primary_key = 'smth' and timestamp > '2022-10-14T06:30:00+0600' and timestamp < '2022-10-14T23:59:59+0600'`, but it's changed nothing.
`Question is:` How can I fetch timestamp with certain/correct timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CQL timestamp data type is [encoded as the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html) (Jan 1, 1970 00:00 GMT) so its value is encoded in UTC timezone. Clients also display timestamps with a UTC timezone by default.

If you want the data to be displayed in your timezone, you need to configure your app or client to a specific timezone. For example, you can configure cqlsh to use a different timezone by specifying it in the `cqlshrc` file:

```
;; Display timezone
timezone = Australia/Melbourne
```

You can find [a sample copy of `cqlshrc` here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cqlshrc.sample). Note that you will need to [install the `pytz` Python library](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to use different timezones with cqlsh.

For details, see [Cassandra CQL shell](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html). Cheers!